# JDBC SELECT COUNT(*) returns empty resultset on HSQLDB

Tags: select, jdbc, count, hsqldb

I would expect to always receive a resultset with one row on a SELECT COUNT, but results.next() always returns false. This is on HSQLDB 2.5.1.
The code below prints:

> number of columns: 1. First column C1 with type INTEGER
>
> No COUNT results

```
           statement = connection.createStatement();
            // check if table empty
            statement.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM mytable");
            ResultSet results = statement.getResultSet();
            System.out.println("number of columns: " + results.getMetaData().getColumnCount() + ". First column " +results.getMetaData().getColumnName(1) + " with type " +results.getMetaData().getColumnTypeName(1) );
            int numberOfRows = 0;
            boolean hasResults = results.next();
            if (hasResults){
                numberOfRows = results.getInt(1);
                System.out.println("Table size " + numberOfRows );
            }else{
                System.out.println("No COUNT results" );
            }
            statement.close();
```

Executing the same SQL statement in my SQL console works fine:

| C1 |
| --- |
| 104 |

Other JDBC actions on this database work fine as well.
Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: I notice from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html that executeQuery returns a ResultSet. I'm not sure about the statefulness of Statement but wondering if that object has the expected row, and the one returned by getResultSet is a different object.

Comment: `ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getResultSet` method is applicable to `execute`, but not `executeQuery` which returns a ResultSet. That is the one you need to refer to, at the moment you are losing it as you are not assigning it to anything.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String) and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getResultSet()

```
ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable");
```